# WPF one app rendering affects other app renderings

Tags: wpf

I have come across a strange problem.

Basically my app has a primary and a secondary window, the latter is shown on the second monitor. The secondary window has a marquee text animation going 24/7. For the secondary window, I had created a seperate thread with its own Dispatcher, so that the primary window's UI thread could not affect it.

Now I found out, that whenever I moved a modal window on the primary window with the mouse, the movement was sluggish and the marquee text animation became jerky. So I figure, that despite the separtae UI threads, the rendering thread is still the same for the entire process.

My next step was to move the second window to it's very own executable (a seperate Visual Studio project). But even with both windows living in their own processes, still the marque text animation becomes jerky when I move a modal window around in the primary window?!?

How can one application affect another application's rendering so drasticaly?
How to overcome this issue?

I'm using Win 7 x64, Core i5, nVidia GTX 670, .NET 4.5.1.

**Edit:**

I tried creating a seperate application with Windows Forms, that had a single Label control moving like a marquee, albeit with a regular timer (interval 15ms).
In my main WPF application I launched the primary window without the secondary window and still, moving a modal window inside the primary window causes the marquee in WinForm app to lag and become jerky :S

Comment: Have you tried to observe the processor load when you move the windows overlapping each other? Perhaps there is something in your render causing the whole render system to glitch.

Comment: Processor load is non existing, 1-2%